# How do I animate div movement when set to 'display:none'?

Tags: html, css

If you have two div elements next to each other, and you set display:none; on div that is on the left side, the right one jumps in to the place where the left one was. Is there any way to animate that jump, that the right element does when left one is display: none;,  so you have smooth transition?

Comment: Please share some code you have tried

Comment: display is not animatable, so maybe setting `width:0;overflow:0` might be useful? [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hogux37f/)

Comment: You can animate left element width to 0 and then set display none.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for you which I believe does what you need:

```
[here] https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/ysrc8cp3/2/
```